# SVN - commit only some changes

Tags: svn

One of the things I like about GIT is that you can commit only some changes in a file. For example if you were doing two different changes which involved the same file, you can commit the file as two separate commits with different comments.

Like:

I spent all day working on a file before realizing that the previous days changes had not been commits, I can do the following by selecting which lines I would like to include in the commit:

```
Login.php [246]: previous changes
Login.php [247]: new changes
```

I realise that this ability is because the changeset in GIT is a DIFF, while SVN simply commits an entire file. Is it possible to have the same behavior with SVN?

If there is a [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) specific hack then that would be alright since that is what we use.

Comment: For those not familiar with git, `git add -p` will give you a color-coded diff of all the line-by-line changes and ask you which changes to commit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use git-svn, I don't think SVN has this support, or rather any of the SVN clients do apart from git-svn or even hgsubversion

---

Some rant:

I don't think the reason you ask for this is a proper one. It means you have to change the way you create changesets and commit. The reason I would want such a feature is for the following reason:

Say there is a build file. It has a certain set of tasks to be done in the build server. For my local box, I comment out the part where it generates installers because I don't need to do that on dev box. Now if at sometime I want to make a change in this build file, I have to undo the part where I removed the installer generation and commit my other change. In this case, I would have liked to have the ability to choose the other change and commit that alone.

Comment: Why didnt I think of that! :-) Thank you. Here is a useful read for anyone interested in using this setup: http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself, but it looks as if you can now do this using Tortoise SVN: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-restore

Comment: this was added in TortoiseSVN v1.8 apparently: http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#commitparts

Answer (score 3):

VisualSVN 6.1 introduces the new **Quick Commit** feature. This feature allows you to perform partial commits for changes such as typo-fixes or code comments without losing focus on the main task.

You can partially commit selected changes in a file using the new **Commit this Block** and **Commit Selection** context menu commands in the Visual Studio editor.

Get VisualSVN at https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/.

[image]